# How can I change this code so that it can complete the loop and finish the calculations

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a calculator to let me know how many waters I need to sell to get my desired profit.

Mainly I want this code to calculate How many waters and packs of water I need to make $380 profit.

My code is not returning an error, but it stops counting at 24 and does not print my f string statements.

```
#packs of water 
n = 1

#profit needed
Profit_needed = 380


#Water cost $5 per pack 
Water_Cost = n*5

# 2 packs of ice per pack of water. Ice pack is $2 each 
Ice_cost = (n*2)*2

# number of ice packs 
Ice_amount = Ice_cost*.5

#profit 
Water_Profit = n*25 -Ice_cost - Water_Cost

while Water_Profit < Profit_needed:
    n = n+1
    print(n)
    Ice_cost = (n*2)*2
    Water_Cost = n*5
    Water_Profit = n*25 -Ice_cost - Water_Cost
    Waters_needed = n*25
    Ice_amount = Ice_cost*.5
 
    if Water_Profit == Profit_needed:
        print(f'{n} is cases need')
        print(f' {Water_Profit} is profit')
        print(f'{Waters_needed} is amount needed to sell')
        print(f' {Water_Cost} is the Water cost')
        print(f' {Ice_cost} is the Ice cost')
        print(f' {Ice_amount} is the Ice bags')
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The title tells us very little about the actual problem, and your experience level is irrelevant.

Comment: It will only print the statements when Water_profit equals Profit_needed, if you want to print the statements when there is profit, put the prints outside the while loop and remove the if condition, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if Water_Profit == Profit_needed:
```

to

```
if Water_Profit >= Profit_needed:
```

Water_profit might never exactly equal profit_needed.

Another thing you could do is to move the prints inside the if to outside the while-loop (without the if condition) since the execution will only reach there if Water_Porfit met the condition you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is excellent,
thing there is , at your loop you just pass by the `380$` profit directly to `384$` from somewhere below `380$`

and your `if` statement is `==` which means equal , now `380 == 384 returns False`

so a Correction would be `if Water_Profit >= Profit_needed:` , if you are interested in the exact amount of 380 , you'll have to add some code to it to deal with float numbers , or find another approach.

```py
#packs of water 
n = 1

#profit needed
Profit_needed = 380


#Water cost $5 per pack 
Water_Cost = n*5

# 2 packs of ice per pack of water. Ice pack is $2 each 
Ice_cost = (n*2)*2

# number of ice packs 
Ice_amount = Ice_cost*.5

#profit 
Water_Profit = n*25 -Ice_cost - Water_Cost

while Water_Profit < Profit_needed:
    n = n+1
    print(n)
    Ice_cost = (n*2)*2
    Water_Cost = n*5
    Water_Profit = n*25 -Ice_cost - Water_Cost
    Waters_needed = n*25
    Ice_amount = Ice_cost*.5

    if Water_Profit >= Profit_needed:
        print(f'{n} is cases need')
        print(f' {Water_Profit} is profit')
        print(f'{Waters_needed} is amount needed to sell')
        print(f' {Water_Cost} is the Water cost')
        print(f' {Ice_cost} is the Ice cost')
        print(f' {Ice_amount} is the Ice bags')
```